# Lost xdebug after 20.04 upgrade

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

After 19.10 to 20.04 upgrade I lost php7.3 xdebug. After complete php reinstall following https://pixelspress.com/how-to-insta...-ubuntu-19-10/ (20.04 version not found), I get that error message:

```
# systemctl reload php7.3-fpm
...
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so: /usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_get_properties_for
```

Here is my php7.3 install state:

```
# dpkg -l *php7.3* |grep ii
ii libapache2-mod-php7.3 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii php7.3 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii php7.3-bcmath 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 Bcmath module for PHP
ii php7.3-bz2 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 bzip2 module for PHP
ii php7.3-cli 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii php7.3-common 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii php7.3-curl 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 CURL module for PHP
ii php7.3-fpm 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii php7.3-gd 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 GD module for PHP
ii php7.3-imagick 3.4.4-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 amd64 Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library
ii php7.3-imap 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 IMAP module for PHP
ii php7.3-intl 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 Internationalisation module for PHP
ii php7.3-json 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 JSON module for PHP
ii php7.3-ldap 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 LDAP module for PHP
ii php7.3-mbstring 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 MBSTRING module for PHP
ii php7.3-mysql 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 MySQL module for PHP
ii php7.3-opcache 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii php7.3-readline 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 readline module for PHP
ii php7.3-recode 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 recode module for PHP
ii php7.3-tidy 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 tidy module for PHP
ii php7.3-xdebug 3.0.1+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 Xdebug Module for PHP
ii php7.3-xml 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii php7.3-xmlrpc 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP
ii php7.3-zip 7.3.24-3+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 Zip module for PHP
```

Any help greatly apreciated

Comment: `/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so` -- that's for PHP **7.4**. PHP 7.4 has `20190902` API level, while PHP 7.3 has `20180731`. Adjust the path accordingly.

Comment: Xdebug has a really great [install wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard) to tell you pretty much all the steps needed for your specific version

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I found the 20180731 and now xdebug seems to work but is it normal that parameters seem have changed when I kept the same php version ?

Following instructions page https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-%22xdebug.remote_host%22 I ended with that for localhost debuging on port 9003 (seems that port default value can't be changed now):

```
# cat /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini 
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
```

Now it works

Comment: You now have Xdebug 3 .. and it uses **different** config parameters than v2 (as you already know). So... just configure it in the same way as v2 just using those new parameter names. E.g. If it used to work on 9000 port then tell Xdebug 3 to use the same 9000 port as before.